# How to find the largest number among 5 in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I want to find it using the IF statements and NESTED IF statements. I know how to find the largest among 3 numbers, but can't do the 5. I want to follow the same concept as the code below:

```
Dim number1, number2, number3, largest as integer
number1= 2
number 2= 7
number3= 14
If number1>number2 then
 if number1>number 3 then
     largest= number1
     else
      largest= number3
      End If
 Else If number2> number3 then
  largest= number2
  else 
      largest number3
 End If
label1.text= largest
```

Comment: `label1.Text = {number1, number2, number3, number4, number5}.Max.ToString` will display the value of the largest number.

Comment: @Blackwood I want it to follow the same concept of the code that I just mentioned. Using NEsted if statements

Comment: just check each number against largest and assign appropriately. `If number1 > largest then largest = number1` repeat for number2 and number3

Comment: Why try and find the largest, according to code you will already know that.. Does a user enter the numbers? As it stands just do this `label1.Text= number3.ToString`... and remove all the nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

By comparing each number to largest and only assigning it if it's larger you will end up with the largest number assigned to largest.

```
    Dim number1, number2, number3, largest As Integer
    number1 = 2
    number2 = 7
    number3 = 14

    ' if 2 > 0 then largest = 2
    If number1 > largest Then largest = number1
    ' if 7 > 2 then largest = 7
    If number2 > largest Then largest = number2
    ' if 14 > 7 then largest = 14
    If number3 > largest Then largest = number3

    label1.text = largest
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic requires some re-thinking. At the moment you are using a brute force approach which, as you have already discovered, becomes more complicated the larger the original set. And your solution is not really maintainable - what if you wanted 4 numbers, 10 numbers etc, you would have to rewrite code all the time.

Modern coding languages include loops and collections to make our lives easier.

```
Function MyMax(Numbers() As Long) As String
    Dim largest As Long = Long.MinValue
    If Numbers.Count > 0 Then   ' it is ok to find the maximum from a single number!
        For iterator = 0 To Numbers.Count - 1
            If Numbers(iterator) > largest Then largest = Numbers(iterator)
            'largest = If(Numbers(iterator) > largest, Numbers(iterator), largest) ' another way of achieving the line above
        Next
        Return largest.ToString
    Else
        Return "Error - no numbers to check!"
    End If
End Function

Sub testMyMax()
    Debug.Print(MyMax({2, 7, 14}))
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks good but it seems to function without `largest = If(Numbers(iterator) > largest, Numbers(iterator), largest)` What am I missing?

Comment: @Mary: You are missing nothing. That second line was supposed to be commented out as an alternative method to achieve the same effect!